# Single Labeling Function not respected by Snorkel

Tags: machine-learning

I have a single labeling function. It returns the positive case when a strings appearns in the text. It happens 53 times out of 42232 cases. The Snorkel label that I get with this single function is always -1.

```
# Define the set of labeling functions (LFs)
lfs = [lf_keyword_filmrechten]

# Apply the LFs to the unlabeled training data
applier = PandasLFApplier(lfs)
L_train = applier.apply(df_train)

# Train the label model and compute the training labels
label_model = LabelModel(cardinality=2, verbose=True)
label_model.fit(L_train, n_epochs=500, log_freq=50, seed=123)
df_train["label"] = label_model.predict(L=L_train, tie_break_policy="abstain")
```

Comment: By now I have discovered predict_proba, but also there it returns always [0.5, 0.5].

The next progress I had was that I've found that if my LF(s) return 0 instead of -1 in the "unknown" case, I do get interesting and relevant probabilities (not just 0.5).

Comment: Upon reading their paper, I am of the understanding that label 0 is for abstaining. +1 = positive label, -1 = negative label and 0 = abstain. Was this your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure yet about the solution, but the discussion can be found here: [github](https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel/issues/1422)